# Cannot access test resource from production class

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I have the following class which I want to unit test:

```
class PropsProvider {

    String propsfileLocation;

    void init() {
        Path path = getPropsPath();
        loadPropertiesFromPath(path);
    }

    private Path getPropsPath() throws URISyntaxException {
        URI fileUri = new URI(propsfileLocation);
        return Paths.get(fileUri); // << failure here
    }

    // ...

}
```

I am unit testing the above class and I keep getting a failure on the line `Paths.get(fileUri)`. I get an `IllegalArgumentException`. I am passing in a relative path from my unit test, which is `src/test/resources/app.properties`. I believe this is happening because I haven't included the prefix `file:`. The unit test resides in the same package as the above class albeit in the `/src/test/java folder`. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the path of any resource using Google's Guava library.

```
URL myFileLocation=Resources.getResource("myFile.txt");
```

For more look here.
http://google.github.io/guava/releases/22.0/api/docs/com/google/common/io/Resources.html#getResource-java.lang.Class-java.lang.String-

Comment: Works beautiful. Thanks